# missing android.support.design -

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to compile a simple app on a new Android Studio bundle installation (after windows reinstall). I've got a compile error:

Could not find com.android.support.design:21.0.3

Okay, in sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design folder I can see only 22.x and 23.x subfolders, so 21 is really missing.

However, in sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7 I can see 18,19,20,21,22 and 23 major versions, and there are appcompat-v7:21.0.3 for what I also have dependency.

First question: how could it be possible? I'm using the SDK manager only, no manual hacking. I thought that it was enough to check the needed components and SDK manager downloaded the corresponding versions.
What can I do to install design:21 ? Or an earlier version?

In SDK manager there's no versions under the entries, I can see only 'Android Support Library' for example, without versions.
Second querstion: how can be determined the versions to be download in SDK manager?

I can see that an "Android Support Repository" entry exists under Extras, there's a screenshot at http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html , for example.
However in my SDK manager there's no such entry! There's only two that have 'repository' in its name: "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries" and "Google Repository". Both of them are installed.
Third question: Is it a bug/confusion in my SDK manager? Or...?

When I start Android Studio and my project is loaded it tries to help me giving an error message, like this:

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:21.0.3
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

The "Install Repository and sync project" is a link. When I click it AS brings up a new window with the text below:

Loading SDK information...
Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Fourth question: what may cause this? It seems there's no such package exists...?

Thanks in advance,
F

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your android studio have not enough downloaded sdk, specialy around sdk 21 version so download it and rebuilt. If studio gives direct link in messages section at botton, just click and start download. Otherwise from sdk manager. Gradually download all required sdk and every error will be reduced.

for error related to support design, put following in gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

you change version in above code as per requirement

sometimes you will see errors like above image, so click on "install repository", it wil automativally start downloading sdk

Comment: Accidentally I pressed an Enter in previous comment and it sent the firs line... sorry. Again: "so download it and rebuilt" - I don't really know how to do that. Under Android 5.0.1 there's checked entries: 'SDK PLatform', 'Intel X86 Atom System Image', 'Google APIs', 'Sources for Android SDK'. What do I have to check or uncheck, or...?  "gives direct link in messages section at botton, just click and start download" - My initial post cites that clicking download caues another error: 'The package filter removed all packages' Could you provide a step-by-step guide how to repair, please?

Comment: Download platform and sources of sdk and tell me what happens